# Does there exist an effective divisor on proper curve over $k$ whose support meets every irreducible component?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ be a proper curve over the field $k$. I want to show that there is some effective Cartier divisor $D \geq 0$ on $X$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(D) \cap X_i \neq \emptyset$ where $X_i$ are the irreducible components of $X$.

My idea is to come up with effective divisors on the components which agree on the overlaps to glue these together. Thus for me this sounds like

- Show the existence of effective divisors on the components
- and then show (with some kind of approximation argument) that these can be chosen to fit together.

But maybe all this follows from a more elegant concept. I appreciate any kind of help or hints!

Comment: Can't you just add some points in the smooth locus of each component of the curve? Is the problem that you want to use finite fields and there might not be any smooth points over $k$?

Comment: @Zach Teitler It definitely need to work over any field.